# How Do I Persist A Scalar Value Across Program Executions?

Tags: perl

Code sample `var_inc1.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
my $x = 0;
$x++;
print "value : ".$x."\n";
```

Output:

- first time: `perl var_inc1.pl`

  ```
  value : 1
  ```
- second time: `perl var_inc1.pl`

  ```
  value : 1
  ```

But I want the output to be

- first time execution: `perl var_inc1.pl`

  ```
  value : 1
  ```
- second time execution: `perl var_inc1.pl`

  ```
  value : 2
  ```
- third time execution: `perl var_inc1.pl`

  ```
  value : 3
  ```

… and so on, where the scalar value increments at each program execution.

Answer (score 8):

Once a Perl program ends, everything in RAM goes away.  If you want a value to be retained between runs of a program you need some form of persistant storage.  What sort of storage you need depends on what you the constraints of you environment and what form of persistance you need (should different users see the same value and be able to change it, how long should it live, etc.).

The simplest (but not the best) way to get persistence in Perl 5 is to use the [`dbmopen`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/dbmopen.html) function to create/open a DBM file associated with a hash:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

dbmopen my %storage, "/tmp/foo.db", 0666 #anyone can write to it
    or die "could not open /tmp/foo.db: $!";

my $x = ++$storage{x};

print "$x\n";
```

In general, `dbmopen` has been replaced by [`tie`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/tie.html), which is a more general way of associating code with variables.  A more modern approach to the code above would be:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use DB_File;

tie my %storage, "DB_File", "/tmp/bar.db"
    or die "could not open /tmp/bar.db: $!";

my $x = ++$storage{x};

print "$x\n";
```

Sometimes you don't want to be dependent on an external resource, in those cases you can just write a self modifying script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $pos = tell DATA;

my $x = <DATA>;

$x++;

open DATA, "+<", $0
    or die "could not open $0 in read/write mode: $!";

seek DATA, $pos, 0
    or die "could not seek to $pos in $0";

print DATA "$x\n"; #save the current value

print "$x\n";

__DATA__
1
```

Note, this only works if all the users who are going to run this script have write permission to the script.  This is a security issue if more than one user is allowed to run the script (because one user could modify the script to include malicious code which would be run by the other users).

Of course, you could also use a relational database:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use DBI;

my $db = "/tmp/baz.db";

my $dbh = DBI->connect(
    "dbi:SQLite:dbname=$db",
    "", # SQLite doesn't do auth, so make sure the file
    "", # permissions are what you need them to be
    {
        AutoCommit       => 1,
        PrintError       => 0,
        RaiseError       => 1,
        ChopBlanks       => 1,
        FetchHashKeyName => "NAME_lc",
    }
) or die "could not connect to $db: ", DBI->errstr;

my $count = $dbh->selectcol_arrayref("
    SELECT count(*)
    FROM sqlite_master
    WHERE type='table'
    AND name='counter';
")->[0];

unless ($count) {
    $dbh->do("
        CREATE TABLE counter (
        name  char(50),
        value int
        );
    ");
    $dbh->do("INSERT INTO counter (name, value) VALUES ('x', 0)");
}

my $x = $dbh->selectcol_arrayref("
    SELECT value
    FROM counter
    WHERE name = 'x'
")->[0];

$x++;

print "$x\n";

$dbh->do("UPDATE counter SET value = ? WHERE name = ?", {}, $x, "x");

$dbh->disconnect;
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is to remember a value between the program invocations.

Two techniques come to mind:

1. You can make the caller remember the value and pass it to the Perl script as an argument.  This is how state is maintained in web applications.  If you have different callers invoking the same program, each will maintain its own counter.
2. You can write and read the value to/from persistent storage, e.g., a file.  If you have multiple different callers invoking the Perl program, this will work to recall the total number of calls, but if multiple invocations may be attempted simultaneously you must take care to open the storage for writing in such a way that only one invocation can have it open at the same time; see e.g. [perlopentut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut.html) if you want to use a file.

Comment: +1 [Storable](http://perldoc.perl.org/Storable.html) might be an easy-to-use option for file based storage.

Comment: @Mike: Easier than a single number? :)

Comment: @jrockway: yes, but a counter that persists between calls to his script. I thought storable might be a reasonable choice, since `The Storable package brings persistence to your Perl data structures containing SCALAR, ARRAY, HASH or REF objects`. Although some of the other suggested solutions may be more appropriate, such as `tie`. Is storable a particularly bad choice? I've still got a lot to learn about Perl...

Comment: Storable converts a data structure to a string to put in a file, like a YAML or JSON serializer.  "print $x" does the same thing when you're talking about numbers.  That's all I'm saying.

Answer (score 0):

You might look at [`DBM::Deep`](http://p3rl.org/DBM%3a%3aDeep) which can tie a database to variable. You use it like a regular Perl <s>scalar</s> hash or array but it automagically stores and retrieves the values using a flat-file database. Edit: Scalars are apparently not included.

Here is an example using a hash to emulate your example.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use DBM::Deep;

my %x;
tie %x, 'DBM::Deep', 'test.db';

$x{'x'}++;
print "value : ". $x{'x'} ."\n";
```