# perl increasing the counter number every time the script  running

Tags: perl

I have a script to compare 2 files  and print out the matching lines on the file. what I want to add a logic to help me to identify for how long these devices are matched. currently I have add the starting point 1 so I want to increase that number every time the script run and matched.

Example.

inputfile:-########################

retiredDevice.txt

> Alpha
>
> Beta
>
> Gamma
>
> Delta

prodDevice.txt

> first
>
> second
>
> third
>
> forth
>
> Gamma
>
> Delta

output file :-#######################

final_result.txt

> 1 Delta
>
> 1 Gamma

my objective is to add a counter stamp on each matching line to identify for how long "Delta" and "Gamma" matched. the script running every week. so every time the script running adding 1 so when I audit the 'finalResult.txt. the result should looks like

> Delta 4
>
> Gamma 3

the result indicate me Delta matched for last 4 weeks and Gamma for last 3 weeks.

```
#! /usr/local/bin/perl 
my $ndays = 1;
my $f1 = "/opt/retiredDevice.txt ";
my $f2 = "prodDevice.txt";
my $outfile = "/opt/final_result.txt";
my %results = ();

open FILE1, "$f1" or die "Could not open file: $! \n";
while(my $line = <FILE1>){   $results{$line}=1;
}
close(FILE1); 
open FILE2, "$f2" or die "Could not open file: $! \n";
while(my $line =<FILE2>) {  
$results{$line}++;
}
close(FILE2); 

open (OUTFILE, ">$outfile") or die "Cannot open $outfile for writing \n";
foreach my $line (keys %results) { 
my $x = $ndays;
$x++;
print OUTFILE "$x : ", $line if $results{$line} != 1;
}
close OUTFILE;
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Does `diff` not suit your needs?

Comment: diff can work my problem is I want to identify for how long been there since I am dealing 6k plus device. i want to focus on device reported for longer time.thx!!

Comment: @eli : Looks like someone asked a similar question recently: [How do I persist a scalar value across program executions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840709/how-do-i-persist-a-scalar-value-across-program-executions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your earlier question and comments, perhaps this might work.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $logfile = 'int.txt';
my $f1 = shift || "/opt/test.txt";
my $f2 = shift || "/opt/test1.txt";
my %results;
open my $file1, '<', $f1;
while (my $line = <$file1>) {
    chomp $line;
    $results{$line} = 1;
}
open my $file2, '<', $f2;
while (my $line = <$file2>) {
    chomp $line;
    $results{$line}++;
}

{ ############ added part
    my %c;
    for (keys %results) {
        $c{$_} = $results{$_} if $results{$_} > 1;
    }
    %results = %c;
} ############ end added part

my (%log, $log);
if ( -e $logfile ) {
    open $log, '<', $logfile;
    while (<$log>) {
        my ($num, $key) = split;
        $log{$key} = $num;
    }
}

open $log, '>', $logfile or die $!;
for my $key (keys %results) {
    my $old = ( $log{$key} || 0 ); # keep old count, or 0 otherwise
    my $new = ( $results{$key} ? 1 : 0 ); # 1 if it exists, 0 otherwise
    print $log $old + $new, " $key\n";
}
```

Comment: thank you so very much for your response. the script working as my objective with minor issue the however counter is perfect!!!the issue is now the output file now contain all devices from  both file1 and file2 instead of print only the matching lists. here is the exact out put. after running 5 time the script. 5 Beta
5 Gamma
5 forth
5 first
5 second
5 third
5 Delta
5 Alpha  -----------------------------------------------------------
the result should be only the matching device ----------------------5 Delta
5 Alpha

Comment: Oh yeah, forgot about that part. Well, that's easy enough. I'll edit the script. See the comment about "added part"

Answer (score 1):

Perform this computation in two steps.

Each time you run the comparison between retired and prod, produce an output file that you save with a unique file name, e.g. result-XXX where XXX denotes when you ran the comparison.

Then write a script which iterates over all of the result-XXX files and produces a summary.

I would name the files result-YYYY-MM-DD where YYYY-MM-DD is the date that the comparison was created. Then it will be relatively easy to iterate over a subset of the files (e.g. ones for a certain month).

Or store the data in a relational database.

Comment: I agree with the advice about the database.  Use sqlite.  Writing a simple SQL statement is easier than writing a whole program every time you want to do a different type of query.